# Python Wand on GoogleAppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Anyone know how to use python wand (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Wand/0.1.10) on google appengine? I've copied the wand directory to my project direcotry but still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for Wand describes it as a Python binding for the ImageMagick API. So there'd be no point in installing it on App Engine, since ImageMagick itself isn't present.